# Opengl does not work in my qml project on raspberry

Tags: qt, opengl-es, qml, raspbian

I am using Qml for drawing a chart. To accelerate it am using the openGl. for example:

```
function plotDataX(routerNumber, sensorNumber, bordar, checked) {
        if(bordar === "x" && checked) {
            var line = chartX.createSeries(ChartView.SeriesTypeLine, routerNumber+" , "+sensorNumber+" , "+bordar,
                                           axisXTime, axisXData);
            line.useOpenGL = true;

            lineSeriesList.push(line)
        }
    }
```

Every thing is fine in my laptop (compile by QT 5.12) but in raspberry pi  it does not show anything, and if I comment the line.useOpengl = true it draws the chart (on raspberry Qt 5.10). On the other hand, I tested the Qt 5.12 qmlosciloscope example on raspberry and it works fine by OpenGl.
Any Idea?

**UPDATE:**

```
qt.scenegraph.general: threaded render loop
qt.scenegraph.general: Using sg animation driver
qt.scenegraph.general: Animation Driver: using vsync: 16.67 ms
qt.scenegraph.general: Using sg animation driver
qt.scenegraph.general: Animation Driver: using vsync: 16.67 ms
qt.scenegraph.general: texture atlas dimensions: 1024x512
qt.scenegraph.general: R/G/B/A Buffers:    5 6 5 0
qt.scenegraph.general: Depth Buffer:       24
qt.scenegraph.general: Stencil Buffer:     8
qt.scenegraph.general: Samples:            0
qt.scenegraph.general: GL_VENDOR:          Broadcom
qt.scenegraph.general: GL_RENDERER:        VideoCore IV HW
qt.scenegraph.general: GL_VERSION:         OpenGL ES 2.0
qt.scenegraph.general: GL_EXTENSIONS:      GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_APPLE_rgb_422  GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_EGL_image GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_texture_npot
qt.scenegraph.general: Max Texture Size:  2048
qt.scenegraph.general: Debug context:     false
```

Comment: I don't know what your code will produce but there are some issues with opengl and raspberry https://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/01/18/opengl-implementation-qt-quick-app-using-today/ try to put the QSG_INFO varitable to equal1 ```qputenv("QSG_INFO", "1");```

Comment: @DraykoonD as I expected it showed there is no problem by finding OpenGl (because qml example runs fine on it). However, I updated the question by this  output (if it will help).

Comment: @DraykoonD also about the code. I do not think it will change things when I just set OpenGL true. I mean, when it is Ok without OpenGL it must be Ok by it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to Qt versions! By Qt 5.10 the problem appeared even on the laptop, and by Qt 5.12 everything works fine on raspberry.